# How to bring a person out of a coma, mushrooms?

Tags: super-powers, biochemistry, brain

How to bring a person out of a coma when doctors can't cope?

The man was dead for 2 hours. I was lying in the swamp water. He was taken to the hospital.

The superhero, a biotechnologist, has healed him, but the man is still in a coma. He's breathing, his heart is beating.

Super-hero-mushroom picker, who has the ability to produce any existing preparations from mushrooms. It can synthesize substances that stimulate the growth of neural stem cells. How can a mushroom picker bring this person out of a coma?

Will the delivery of controlled fungi that synthesize stem cells in different parts of the brain help?

Transcranial magnetic stimulation? Electrical brain stimulation?

the brain spent two hours without oxygen. The bio-tech didn't touch the brain, it's outside of his specialty

the patient is dead but the heart is beating and the lungs are breathing.

can some neurons be revived by neuro-stem cells, neurogenesis, and electrical stimulation, by feeding nutrients through a syringe or a mushroom colony?

Will the patient come to life if some neurons are replaced with new, live ones grown in a test tube?

update
ок its a new plan
the idea is as follows: slow down the further degradation of the brain in the hope of finding superpowers that can help

my English is bad

Comment: What are the specific details of his current medical condition, ie. what's keeping him in a coma?

Comment: the brain scanner does not see glucose radiation in those areas of the brain where they are usually located when a person is conscious or just asleep.

the brain spent two hours without oxygen. 
The bio-tech didn't touch the brain, it's outside of his specialty.

Comment: So then, they're dead? You're asking us what drug can resurrect someone? We don't have the tech to scan for glucose, nor to resurrect. What are you really wanting to achieve? Could you [edit] the question with all the necessary details to make us understand what you're after.

Comment: I think doing some research to [get a better idea of how and why coma occurs](https://brainfoundation.org.au/disorders/coma/#:~:text=Someone%20who%20is%20in%20a,be%20unresponsive%20to%20their%20environment.) might help you understand the details of the situation you're facing and even potentially answer your question altogether.

Comment: Also, if the brain spent 2 hours without oxygen and the person wasn't frozen, it's dead. The brain can only last a maximum of ~4 minutes without oxygen, at which point it will start to suffer permanent damage. The brain will die completely after a period of 8 to 10 minutes without oxygen. If your person spent 15 times that period of time without oxygen and the magic biotech didn't touch it, it's still 100% dead. You might as well dissect them and check what exactly is maintaining their bodily functions, cause it sure ain't their ANS and you might have a case of body snatching brain parasites.

Comment: @ARogueAnt.doesn't Functional magnetic resonance imaging indicates brain activity due to the presence of glucose in the active regions?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. thx. edited

Comment: Alas, no, fMRI measures oxygenated blood-flow.

Comment: If your victim had been in ice-water, 2 hours might leave the brain damaged but repairable. 2 hours in a swamp, with no oxygen, would have killed off the neurons in the brain (and spine). Even 30 minutes is way past recovery.

Answer (score 7):

/Will the patient come to life if some neurons are replaced with new, live ones grown in a test tube?/

**Maybe.**

[image: swamp thing]

https://www.ign.com/articles/2019/05/31/swamp-thing-explained-who-is-the-dc-character

What can reverse death?  In Swamp Thing, a man died in the swamp and his form and his memory were copied by the life of the swamp.  This new thing came back as an echo of the man who had been.  Your mushroom superhero does not know what he is doing, trying to bring a dead man back.  The fungal elements can copy and replace the dead animal tissue that was there.  The dead man might get off the table.

He is not the same as he was.

Answer (score 1):

> the brain spent two hours without oxygen.

If you are aiming for realism, the patient is dead. Most neuroscience works state the survival rates for over 8 minutes of hypoxia ranging from very unlikely to impossible. Some quick googling leads to results [such as this](https://www.spinalcord.com/blog/what-happens-after-a-lack-of-oxygen-to-the-brain), which states that:

> At 15 minutes, survival becomes nearly impossible.

And if the brain is without oxygen for that long, the sinoatrial node would soon stop, so the only way to keep the heart beating after the first few minutes would be by artificially stimulating it. Otherwise the protagonist would have a sudden cardiac arrest.

Comment: what if... A hero with the super-power of a healer, will clean blood vessels and small capillaries, replace blood, restore heartbeat and lung function, doctors perform electro-cranial brain stimulation. Is it possible to transfer a person from death to a coma in this way?  the idea is as follows: slow down the further degradation of the brain in the hope of finding superpowers that can help

Comment: @g0ldenlights not realistically. Think of this: if your character gets that brain working again it is not healing anymore, but rather necromancy. After fifteen minutes of hypoxia every neuron inside the cranium would be dead and extremely damaged.